# Finding the supremum of $A=\{(6n^2-5)/(4-3n^2):n\geq 2\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We're given $$A = \left\{\frac{6n^2-5}{4-3n^2} : n\geq2\right\}$$
Prove that $A$ is bounded above and below. Find the supremum of $A$ and prove it is the supremum.

Need to prove this using basic properties, without use of limits and derivatives:

So after rewriting the original expression.

Suppose supremum S < -2 (we've shown that -2 is lower bound, therefore no need to show that a greater lower bound exists):

-2 -s = ε >0

s = -2 -ε

-2+(3/(4-3n²) ≤ s = -2 -ε

(3/(4-3n²) ≤  -ε

3/-ε ≤ (4-3n²)

(3/-ε) -4 ≤ -3n²

(3/ε) +4 ≥ 3n²

(1/ε) + (4/3) ≥ n² ≥ n

and thats a contradiction to the Archimedean property

Comment: Thanks for posing the question. You do not intend to do anything yourself?

Comment: I doubt you actually mean infinitesimal calculus.  That would mean you're doing something like [non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The derivative $\frac{dA(n)}{dn}$ is always positive  when $n\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

So where (in $n$) must it attain its lower bound?

And since the derivative is positive and it has no discontinuities, $\sup(A)$ agrees with the limit of $A$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ .

Answer (score 0):

we have for $n \geq2$ $$\frac{6n^2-5}{4-3n^2}<2$$ if $$-5>-8$$
further we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{6n^2-5}{4-3n^2}=-2$$
additional we obtain $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{9(2n+1)}{(3n^2+6n-1)(3n^2+4)}>0$$ for all $n$ with $$n\geq 2$$

Answer (score 0):

For all $n\geq 2$,
$$\frac{6n^2-5}{4-3n^2}=2\frac{6n^2-5}{8-6n^2}=-2\frac{6n^2-5}{6n^2-8}=-2\left(\frac{6n^2-8}{6n^2-8}+\frac{3}{6n^2-8}\right)=-2-\frac{6}{6n^2-8}.$$
Since $n\geq 2$, $6n^2-8\geq 0$, so $-\frac{6}{6n^2-8}\leq 0$. I believe you can complete from here.